# How to access two different object using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have different kind of response and unfortunately I don't have control to change the response, so I can access only in ajax success method.

```
{"message":"Request completed","status":1}{"coin_message":"Thank You! Your....."}
```

Following script I have tried so far but still failed to access it

```
success: function(response){    
   if(response.coin_message){
         $('#response-from-controller-coin-payment').append('<div class="coin_messages alert alert-success" role="alert">'+response.coin_message+'</div>');
   }
   if(response.amount){
       $('#response-from-controller-coin-payment').append('<div class="coin_messages alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+response.amount+'</div>');
   }

   if(response.currency){
       $('#response-from-controller-coin-payment').append('<div class="coin_messages alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+response.currency+'</div>');
   }
}
```

Can someone kindly guide me how can I access the response, I would appreciate. Thank you so much.

Comment: share full response JSON string

Comment: I don't even think that is a valid response.

Comment: @sarvonks this is full response

Comment: The response isn't valid JSON

Comment: @phuzi yes true but still I need to use it. So is there any possibility?

Comment: its not valid JSON

Comment: Isn't that meant to be an array? `[{message: "Request completed"}, {...}]`?

Comment: the condition should be like if(response.coin_message || response.amount || response.currency){ // do something }

Comment: @JackBashford No, in response I am not receiving any array, only this response which I have shared in the question

Comment: Your response should have been an array of objects at the least so that they can be accessed like response[0].message, response[1].coin_message and so on

Comment: what are you getting when you check `typeof response`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't format thuis JSON beacuse it's not valid JSON. Instead, you should parse it yourself.

If there is not nested objects, that's easy: simply split the string after the first `}`. For example,

```
success: function(response) {
  var firstObj = $.parseJSON(response.substring(0, response.indexOf('}' + 1)));
  var secondObj = $.parseJSON(response.substring(response.indexOf('}' + 1)));

  // ...
}
```

And append `dataType: 'text'` to ajax options.

Answer (score 0):

This not valid JSON format. but you can achieve by this way

```
success: function(response) {
  var res= `[${response}]`.replace("}{","},{");
  var [firstObj,secondObj]= eval(res)

}
```